# If I Donate a Glacial Chasm, will my opponent have to sacrifice a land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Glacial Chasm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGlacial%20Chasm%5d)

Based on feedback a few months ago from here, I'm going to use this in conjunction with Donate to 'gift' my opponent some hell! However, one question and I could easily see this going either direction.

> When Glacial Chasm enters the battlefield, sacrifice a land.

So, of course when it enters my battlefield, I sacrifice my land. However, once I DONATE it to the opponent and it enters HIS battlefield, does he sacrifice a land as well?

One could argue it does not say enters YOUR battlefield. Thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Can you please write the actual question that you're asking in the title, instead of a "clever" title or a description of the question?

Comment: Kind of snotty... forgive a new player trying to be creative. Grouch.

Comment: I'm sorry; I didn't mean to offend. But on this site we care about post quality, and part of that is having question titles that accurately reflect/summarize the content of your question. At this point, you've asked 13 questions, and most have required edits to get useful titles. It would be beneficial, both for the site's quality and for your chances of getting a useful answer for you to learn from those edits to write more descriptive titles for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only 1 battlefield, so donating Glacial Chasm doesn't make it re-enter the battlefield.

> 403.3. Permanents exist only on the battlefield. Every object on the battlefield is a permanent. See rule 110, “Permanents.”
>
> 403.5 Previously, the battlefield was called the “in-play zone.” Cards that were printed with text that contains the phrases “in play,” “from play,” “into play,” or the like are referring to the battlefield. Cards that were printed with that text have received errata in the Oracle card reference.

Also, since it has cumulative upkeep, the opponent could just choose not to pay the upkeep and have to sacrifice the land.  If you could donate at instant speed, it could essentially be a fog, but only for one turn.